# Which tool do you recommend for keeping XLIFF (.xlf) translation files in sync?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, internationalization, xliff

I have an internationalized Angular project, using Angular's built-in i18n framework, where the translation files look like this:

**messages.en.xlf**

```
<trans-unit id="7380085404224719862" datatype="html">
   <source>Place a new request</source>
   <context-group purpose="location">
       <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/components/foo.component.html</context>
       <context context-type="linenumber">13</context>
   </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

**messages.de.xlf**

```
<trans-unit id="7380085404224719862" datatype="html">
   <source>Place a new request</source>
   <target>Einen neuen Antrag stellen</target>
   <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/components/foo.component.html</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">13</context>
   </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

where messages.en.xlf is the source file that is automatically generated by the `ng extract-i18n` tool, and the other translation files such as messages.de.xlf are copies of that with translations added manually by a human translator.

There are 3 problems with this workflow as I understand it:

1. If I add or remove some lines in the beginning of `foo.component.html` then the line numbers referenced in the above files will change. For the source file this will happen automatically the next time I re-run the `ng extract-i18n` tool, but for the other translation files do I need to update them manually?
2. If I add a new text to the application, this will result in a new `<trans-unit>` in the source file, which I then need to manually copy to the other translation files.
3. Likewise, if I remove a text from the the application, I will need to manually remove the corresponding `<trans-unit>` from the other translation files.

It is very obvious that all 3 issues could (and should) be very easily automated by some tool, as syncing these files manually is extremely time consuming and error-prone. However I was shocked to see that IntelliJ does not seem to provide this functionality, and the same goes for all i18n/localization/xliff IntelliJ plugins I tried. Am I missing something here? Which tools do you use to keep your .xlf files in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [ng-extract-i18n-merge](https://github.com/daniel-sc/ng-extract-i18n-merge) and I'm very happy with how it works. It handles everything quite transparently and offers a lot of configuration.
As soon as I change a translation id or content, the changes get reflected in all my `xlf` files, keeping them perfectly in sync.

This is of course a dev-dependency and not a plugin for intellij, but I guess that doesn't matter too much. If you need a small handy tool for editing translations, give [TinyTranslator](https://martinroob.github.io/tiny-translator/en/#/home) a go.

Comment: The ng-extract-i18n-merge tool does exactly what I was looking for and is super easy to use. Thanks!